# OS X NFS Automount: "locallocks" ignored?

Tags: nfs

I'm having an issue with file-locking and auto mounting on OS X.

Here is my `auto_master` file:

```
#
# Automounter master map
#
+auto_master        # Use directory service
/net            -hosts      -nobrowse,hidefromfinder,nosuid
/home           auto_home   -nobrowse,hidefromfinder
/Network/Servers    -fstab
/-          -static
/- /etc/auto_nfs
```

And here is `auto_nfs`:

```
# Common Configuration

/Shared/Family          -fstype=nfs,rw,nodev,nosuid,nfc,locallocks nfs://10.0.0.11/Volumes/PDISK3/VDISKS/General1/Groups/Family\ Shared
/Shared/Users/christopher   -fstype=nfs,rw,nodev,nosuid,nfc,locallocks nfs://10.0.0.11/Volumes/PDISK3/VDISKS/General1/Users/christopher
/Shared/Scratch1        -fstype=nfs,rw,nodev,nosuid,nfc,locallocks nfs://10.0.0.11/Volumes/PDISK2/VDISKS/Scratch1

# END Common Configuration
```

**It appears as though `locallocks` is ignored** (the `mount` command doesn't show it and `chflags` fails and Finder's info window has a greyed-out Locked box). I've tried all combinations (e.g. `nolocks`, `nolocks,locallocks`, etc) to no avail.

While I'm OK with not having locks in general on the NFS side, having the lack of even a facade of locks is causing OS X to go *insane* if I try to have home directories on the NFS mount.

**So: how do I get locks (or even a facade of locks) to work on an NFS share?**

Misc details:

The server is an NFS4 server on Linux Mint with exports like this:

```
/Volumes/PDISK2 10.0.0.2(rw,async,no_subtree_check,insecure,no_root_squash) 10.0.0.3(rw,async,no_subtree_check,insecure,no_root_squash) 10.0.0.0/16(rw,async,no_subtree_check,insecure)
/Volumes/PDISK3 10.0.0.2(rw,async,no_subtree_check,insecure,no_root_squash) 10.0.0.3(rw,async,no_subtree_check,insecure,no_root_squash) 10.0.0.0/16(rw,async,no_subtree_check,insecure)
/Volumes/PDISK4 10.0.0.2(rw,async,no_subtree_check,insecure,no_root_squash) 10.0.0.3(rw,async,no_subtree_check,insecure,no_root_squash) 10.0.0.0/16(rw,async,no_subtree_check,insecure)
```

(Note: this computer is not one of the computers given root access and will remain that way).

If I set `no_auth_rlm` on the server, the Locked checkbox is no longer greyed out in the Finder but it won't let me check it (it unchecks itself). If I do this: `touch a ; chflags uchg a` on one of the mounts, I get:

```
chflags: a: Operation not supported
```

Interestingly, `chflags nouchg a` works, but still doesn't allow `chflags uchg a` afterwards. Note that it also doesn't work as root from one of the computer given root access.

The accounts are all from an OS X El Capitan Open Directory server. Yes, it is set up correctly (I can absolutely access/write/edit/etc everything, with the exception what what's apparently an OS X bug w.r.t deleting directories from the Finder).

This is cross-posted because there are two main groups who may have come across this: SysAdmins who have integrated OS X into directory groups (hence ServerFault) and OS-X enthusiasts who have tried to do the same thing personally or for a small business and had issues (hence Think Different).

More information, provided by "Heinrich":

This is not really an auto mount problem. Is seems that the mount(8), or mount_nfs(8) program simply ignores most options:

```
> mount_nfs -o lock,rsize=65535 newserver:/Volumes/Newdata/kits /mnt

> mount|grep /mnt

newserver:/Volumes/Newdata/kits on /mnt (nfs)

> umount /mnt

> mount_nfs -o lock,nodev newserver:/Volumes/Newdata/kits /mnt

> mount|grep /mnt

newserver:/Volumes/Newdata/kits on /mnt (nfs, nodev)
```

"nodev" is honored, but everything else seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that mount options aren't actually ignored, it's just that `mount` does not show them. `nfsstat -m` shows the NFS parameters given and the actual mount options currently in use for each mount.

`locallocks` in particular *does* have an effect: In my setup (macOS Sierra with NFS mounts from a Linux server), the Photos app initially didn't work with its library on the NFS mount (it just hung on start). Only after setting `locallocks` the Photos app could be used.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, locallocks is ignored (or at least not properly working) on OSX for NFSv4. Use `nfsvers=3` as mount option.